# Read complex json file in python

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop, if-statement

Actual Json is:

```
{
  "title1": {
    "titleID": "1234",
    "titlename": "a-b-c",
  },
  "title2": [
    {
      "block": "0.0.0.0/26",
      "abc_id": "abc-0123",
      "tags": [{ "key": "Name", "value": "abc-name"},
               { "key": "env", "value": "dev"}]
    },
    {
      "block": "1.2.0.0/26",
      "abc_id": "abc-4567"
    },
    {
      "block": "0.0.0.0/26",
      "abc_id": "abc-8999",
      "tags": [{ "key": "Name", "value": "xyz-name"}]
    },
    {
      "block": "0.0.0.0/26",
      "abc_id": "abc-7766",
      "tags": [{ "app": "Name", "value": "web-app"}]
    }

  ]
}
```

My Code is

```
with open('/tmp/temp.json') as access_json:
    read_content = json.load(access_json)
    for key1, value1 in read_content.items():
        if key1 == "title1":
            title_id = value1['titleID']
        if key1 == "title2":
            title2_access = read_content['title2']
            for title2_data in title2_access:
                for key2, value2 in title2_data.items():
                    if key2 == "abc_id":
                        abc_id = value2
                    if key2 == "tags":
                        tags_access = read_content['tags'] 
                        for tags_data in tags_access:
                            for key3, value3 in tags_data.items():
                                if key3 == "Name":
                                    abc_name = value3
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 123, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(temp_file_path, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-lw031e0z/tsf_dev.py", line 160, in <module>
KeyError: 'tags'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise e_type(e_value).with_traceback(new_stack)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-lw031e0z/tsf_dev.py", line 160, in <module>
KeyError: KeyError('tags',)
```

Reason: All the items in the title2 dict will not contain "tags". so, if there is no 'tags' or the tags['name'], then the **abc_name = ''**

i need the list of lists
**(titleID, abc_id, abc_name)**.

Expected output :

```
['1234','abc-0123','abc-name']
['1234','abc-4567','']
['1234','abc-8999','xyz-name']
['1234','abc-7766','']
```

There is a dictionary of "title2",
and it contains abc_id and few items contains "tags" as well. 
If there is no tags, then the abc-name should be ''.
If there is no Key: "name", then the abc-name should be ''.
If there is tags and the key: "name" in the dict, then the abc-name should be the value present in the title2[tags][value: ""] where title2[tags][key is "name"]

Comment: is the variable “read_content” what you think it is?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: or the `tags['name'],` what does this mean? there's no such key anywhere in the code

Comment: Please edit the __full__ error message into your question.

Comment: Why don’t you do some simple debugging: add some print statements in each of your `for` loops so you can see the values of variables that are affecting your code? The printout just before the exception will help you figure out what’s going wrong.

Comment: No, around that key error there is some other stuff like `Exception...’ - put __all__that into the question. This is often referred to as a traceback. It includes the code of the line where the exception happened.

Comment: There yu go, wasn’t so hard wwas it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `if` statements and for-loops to properly handle your code. Use the default option for the dictionary `get` method to handle the cases where the data doesn't exist like shown below.

```
title_id = read_content.get('title1', {}).get('titleID', '')

for block in read_content['title2']:
    id_ = block.get('abc_id', '')
    tags = block.get('tags', [{}])
    for tag in tags:
        if tag.get('key', '') == 'Name':
            name = tag.get('value', '')
        else:
            name = ''
        vals = [title_id, id_, name]
        print(vals)

['1234', 'abc-0123', 'abc-name']
['1234', 'abc-0123', '']
['1234', 'abc-4567', '']
['1234', 'abc-8999', 'xyz-name']
['1234', 'abc-7766', '']
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your code, its so simple but only if the tags[key: "name"] then it should take as abc-name value.

Can you please see the question. again. You will understand clearly.